# Where is the /etc folder on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Where is the /etc folder on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and how can I access it?  I'm receiving a "No such file or directory error" and I'd like to understand the path and directory structure of EB better.

As a background, I'm trying to setup a cron job on EB via a .config file in the .ebextensions folder.  The syntax in the file is:

container_commands:
 01_cron_job:
    command: "cat /sendy/.ebextensions/list_import.txt > /etc/cron.d/list_import_cron_job && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/clist_import_cron_job"
    leader_only: true"

When this is deployed I receive the "No such file.." error for "/etc/cron.d/clist_import_cron_job"

The 'list_import.txt' file has the actual CRON syntax.

Comment: Perhaps you should show the exact command you are running. I'd be surprised if the `/etc` folder wasn't there.

Comment: cat /sendy/.ebextensions/list_import.txt > /etc/cron.d/list_import_cron_job && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/clist_import_cron_job" leader_only: true

Comment: You have a typo in your command. In the first part you create a file named `list_import_cron_job` in the second part you try to `chmod` a file named `clist_import_cron_job`. Notice the second part has an extra `c` as a leading character in the filename. (and this is why you should always post what you are trying to accomplish, and your actual error message, when posting questions).